# How to set up multicast from udp connection without knowing ip?

Tags: c, sockets, server, multicast, multicastsocket

I'm having trouble understanding where to even begin i've established a connection between client and server having to use an ip. How would i modify my code to look for a server that's multicasting?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include<netinet/in.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
  
#define PORT 5000
#define MAXLINE 1000
  
// Driver code
int main()
{
    char buffer[100];
    char *message = "Hello Server";
    int sockfd, n;
    struct sockaddr_in servaddr;
      
    // clear servaddr
    bzero(&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    servaddr.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
      
    // create datagram socket
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
      
    // connect to server
    if(connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr)) < 0)
    {
        printf("\n Error : Connect Failed \n");
        exit(0);
    }
  
    // request to send datagram
    // no need to specify server address in sendto
    // connect stores the peers IP and port
    sendto(sockfd, message, MAXLINE, 0, (struct sockaddr*)NULL, sizeof(servaddr));
      
    // waiting for response
    recvfrom(sockfd, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0, (struct sockaddr*)NULL, NULL);
    puts(buffer);
  
    // close the descriptor
    close(sockfd);
}
```

Comment: Start by looking at some examples in the tags you've applied on this question.

Comment: You'd need to know the multicast IP address that the server is multicasting to.  Once you have that it's a matter of calling `setsockopt(sockfd, IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, ...)` to tell the OS that you want your socket to receive multicast packets from that multicast-group.

Comment: Btw I suggest not calling `connect()` on a UDP socket; it is unnecessary (as long as you call `sendto()` and/or `recvfrom()` rather than `send()` and/or `recv()`) and it will prevent your socket from receiving incoming UDP packets if they are not coming from the exact location specified in the `connect()` call.